# How to use Google Cloud Vision API client for nodejs to detect multiple types

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I am trying to use the @google-cloud/vision package to send requests to the Google Vision API. Is there a way to do multiple detections without doing something like:

```
client
  .labelDetection(link)
  .then(...)

client
  .safeSearchDetection(link)
  .then(...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The [`@google-cloud/vision` package](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/) that you are using (or at least the latest version available as of writing, which is `0.19.x`) offers [a variety of methods](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#methods), each of which performs a different type of operation.

In your question, you refer to the methods [`labelDetection`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#labelDetection) and [`safeSearchDetection`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#safeSearchDetection). These are specific methods that perform the [label detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels) and the [Safe Search detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#safe_search) implementations of the Cloud Vision API, respectively.

Instead of using those feature-specific methods, you are interested in using [`annotateImage`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient#annotateImage) instead, which annotates a single image with the features that you specify in the `request.feature` parameter. This parameter is an array object that can include as many features as you want.

Below there is a sample code that would perform Label Detection and Safe Search Detection over a single image in a single call:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const request = {
  image: {source: {imageUri: 'gs://your/GCS/image.jpg'}},
  features: [{type: vision.types.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}, {type: vision.types.Feature.Type.SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION}],
};

client
  .annotateImage(request)
  .then(...);
```

Finally, here you have [the list of available feature types](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/0.19.x/google.cloud.vision.v1#.Type).

Answer (score 3):

Solved it this way for version 0.21.0

```
import * as vision from '@google-cloud/vision';
const visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const request = {
                "image": {
                    "source": {
                        "imageUri": imageUri
                    }
                },
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "FACE_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "WEB_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "CROP_HINTS"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "IMAGE_PROPERTIES"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LOGO_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "LANDMARK_DETECTION"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"
                    },
                    // Other detection types here...
                ]
        };

        return await visionClient.annotateImage(request).then((res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        });
```

with the help of `@dsesto`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value