# Can't change MaxResults on Cloud Vision Labeling

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Vision to detect photos on an image and the results are limited to the top 10. I want to extend this number to 50. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  for (const file of allFiles) {
    if (file.metadata.contentType.startsWith("image/")) {
      const [resultImageLabel] = await client.labelDetection(
        `gs://${bucketName}/${file.name}`
      );

      const labels = resultImageLabel.labelAnnotations;
      const faceDetection = resultFaceDetection.faceAnnotations;

      const labelArray = [];
      const labelScore = {};

      // image Labelling
      for (const label of labels) {
        labelArray.push(label.description);
        labelScore[label.description] = label.score;
      }

      console.log(labelArray);
      console.log(labelScore);
    }
  }
```

The answers that i've seen are in JSON format so i added at the beginning of the for loop:

```
const request = {
      image: {
        source: { imageUri: `gs://${bucketName}/${file.name}` },
      },
      features: [
        {
          maxResults: 50,
        },
      ],
    };

// Changed from image path to request
const [resultImageLabel] = await client.labelDetection(request);
```

Then I get the following error:

> functions: Error: Setting explicit features is not supported on this
> method. Use the #annotateImage method instead.

Looked through the "#annotateImage" documentation and I don't see what I'm missing.

When I comment out the "features" section of the code, everything works as before.

This is running in an https Firebase Cloud Function.

Comment: Can you try `await client.annotateImage` instead of `await client.labelDetection` in your code? Please let me know if this is helpful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements,you can consider the following code below as an example:

```
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
async function testing(){

const allFiles = [
{ name: 'gs://bucket_name/file1.jpeg', metadata: { contentType: 'image/jpeg' } },
];

for (const file of allFiles) {
if (file.metadata.contentType.startsWith("image/")) {
const request = {
image: {
source: { imageUri: file.name },
},
features: [
{
type: 'LABEL_DETECTION',
maxResults: 50,
},
],
};

const [resultImageLabel] = await client.annotateImage(request);
const labels = resultImageLabel.labelAnnotations;
const labelArray = [];
const labelScore = {};

for (const label of labels) {
labelArray.push(label.description);
labelScore[label.description] = label.score;
}
console.log(labelArray);
console.log(labelScore);
}
} 
} 

testing();
```

Sample image used :https://unsplash.com/photos/wfwUpfVqrKU

From the error message it is clear that `features’ is not supported on the labelDetection method so instead that method we have to use the ‘annotateImage’ method.You can find more information from these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932603/) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/vision/latest#.Type).